# Increase width of trendline in scatterPlot openpyxl

Tags: excel, regression, openpyxl

I am using openpyxl scatterplot for displaying Linear Regression trendline in excel chart but the font of the line as well the equation displayed is too small. I am checking if there is a way to increase the font size of both.

Following is my code

```py
chart = ScatterChart()

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=file_path)
ws = wb[SHEET_NAME]

x_values = Reference(ws, min_col=x_col + 1, min_row=2, max_row=ws.max_row)
y_values = Reference(ws, min_col=y_col + 1, min_row=2, max_row=ws.max_row)

series = Series(y_values, x_values, title_from_data=True)

chart.series.append(series)

line_props = LineProperties(solidFill=ColorChoice(prstClr=self.CLR_TREND_LINE))

g_props = GraphicalProperties(ln=line_props)

trend_line = Trendline(spPr=g_props, dispEq=True, dispRSqr=True)

line = chart.series[0]

line.trendline = trend_line
line.graphicalProperties.line.noFill = True
line.marker.symbol = "circle"
```

I want to increase the font of the line and equation represented by circle in the graph below

[image]

Comment: This sort of thing usually is difficult to do with Openpyxl might require a bit or research to see. Xlsxwriter and Xlwing can probably do the trend line. The text is a `textframe`  again the later two modules are more likely to be able to achieve but probably need a bit of research if they are suitable for your use. Xlsxwriter only creates xlsx files it cannot open and change existing files. Xlwings needs Excel so is Windows and MACOS only and MACOS might not support every Xlwings feature [fully]